# Puppeteer Sharp - get html after js finished running

Tags: c#, web-scraping, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am using .net core 3.1 and Puppeteer Sharp 2.0.4.
I want to get the full page HTML from a web page after the JavaScript has finished running.
This is my code:

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false
});
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
page.DefaultTimeout = 0;
var navigation = new NavigationOptions
{
    Timeout = 0,
    WaitUntil = new[] {
        WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded }
};
await page.GoToAsync("https://someurl", navigation);
content = await page.GetContentAsync();
```

It looks like the *content* variable does not have the HTML **after** the JS finished running. Any advice on what I should change to make it work?

Comment: First, you don't need SetJavaScriptEnabledAsync. Second, you should find a way to know that the page is ready. Is there any element that is there once is ready? a javascript variable?

Comment: I have found this element WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded. I have edited my code accordingly and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, could you please share the solution ?

Comment: I have edited the code in the answer, the code there now is the one that works.

Answer (score 1):

Just replacing `navigation` with `WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2` worked to wait until Javascript is finished to excute.

```
using PuppeteerSharp;

await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true // false if you need to see the browser
});
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
page.DefaultTimeout = 5000; // or you can set this as 0
await page.GoToAsync("https://www.google.com", WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2);
var content = await page.GetContentAsync();

Console.WriteLine(content);
```